# QtCreator wont start anymore. Symbol lookup error

Tags: 13.04, qt-creator

Since yesterday I'm unable to start QtCreator. Trying to start QtCreator from terminal gives me this error message, which I haven't found anything on:

```
qtcreator: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: undefined symbol: _ZN15QPlatformWindow17formatWindowTitleERK7QStringS2_
```

Any ideas what this is about?

Running Ubuntu 13.04 with qt5-edgers ppa for both Ubuntu SDK and Qt.

Version of QtCreator: 2.7.0-0ubuntu4~raring1~test5

Comment: Did you change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in your .bashrc file?

Comment: I've not done that recently, no. What should it be set to?

Comment: Searching a bit in google revealed that you may have installed 2 versions of Qt in a single system. I am not sure, though.

Comment: Like Qt4 and Qt5?

Comment: Thanks hakermania, I removed all Qt4 stuff and it works now.

Comment: If someone gets this issue again, please run at least the following: nm -D /usr/lib/*/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so | grep PlatformWindow.*formatWindow

Comment: Also contact me (Mirv on IRC) so that me or someone else can try to get to the root of the problem. The problem seems rare, and it does not seem to be about any missing package. Removing libqt5core5 to remove most of Qt5 and installing ubuntu-sdk again seems to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow it seemed like I had two Qt versions installed (thanks hakermania). After I've removed all Qt4 stuff and reinstalled Ubuntu SDK and QtCreator (again) it worked.

Answer (score 4):

The problem happens rarely but is related to upgrading from for example the archive version of ubuntu-sdk, or maybe some more complex upgrade path. The root problem is currently unknown, but removing and reinstalling Qt 5 seems to work.

1. Remove libqt5core5 package, to remove most of the Qt 5
2. Install ubuntu-sdk package to get the Qt 5 and the rest of the Ubuntu SDK back.